# How can i implement a listener for the gps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an iPad app and wish to call a function every 0.1 miles I travel from a certain x start position . How can i implement this listener ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) docs and a [tutorial is here](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/).

Disclaimer : I haven't read through the whole tutorial; if it's not good enough all I did was google for 'cllocationmanager tutorial' ;)